# jquery get users location using promises and reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, es6-promise, reverse-geocoding

```js
  //Get Users Current Location
  $("#collection-search-geolocation").click(function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
    var zipcode = '';

    getCurrentLocation().then(function(results) {
     console.log('done');
     zipcode = extractZipcode(results);
     callCollectionMap(zipcode);
    });

          return false;
  });

  function extractZipcode(results) {
   var searchAddressComponents = results[0].address_components;
   var zipcode = searchAddressComponents.find(function(el) {
    return el.types[0] == "postal_code";
   }).short_name;
  }
 
  function getCurrentLocation() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latLng   = new google.maps.LatLng( 
     position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
     
     geocoder.geocode(
      {'latLng': latLng}
     , function(results, status){
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       console.log(results);
       deferred.resolve(results);
      } else {
       deferred.reject(status);
       console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
     });

     return deferred.promise();
   });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="collection-search-geolocation" href="#" class="button collection-point-search-geo-js">Click Here</a>
```

I am trying to get a user's location on click. On click, I want to grab the user's location then call a method after geocode is done executing successfully. Here is my code, but geocode is asynchronous hence why I need to use promises.

My issue is that results is returning null in the click function because geocode.geocoder hasn't finished, but I thought that is what .done() is supposed to wait until it finishes? I tried .then() as well and same result. I get the error cannot read property .done() of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the deferred inside the getCurrentPosition callback - returning it there does not mean it is being returned by `getCurrentLocation` - you need to create the deferred outside th getCurrentPosition call, `return deferred.promise()` as the last line of that function, but keep the resolve/reject where it is

so, something like

```
function getCurrentLocation() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latLng
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results);
                deferred.resolve(results);
            } else {
                deferred.reject(status);
                console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Personally, I'd avoid jQuery `Deferred` as it is not a true Promise/A+ implementation (maybe in 3.x it is, but ..) and you have tagged the question with **es6-promise**

```
function getCurrentLocation() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            geocoder.geocode({
                'latLng': latLng
            }, function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    console.log(results);
                    resolve(results);
                } else {
                    reject(status);
                    console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```